# How can a object be child of both AnyVal and AnyRef in Scala3.x

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-3

Why does all of these return true, while for AnyVal returns error on scala 2.x

```
class Demo
val d = new Demo
d.isInstanceOf[Any]
```

-> true

```
d.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]
```

-> true

```
d.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
```

-> true

Comment: Looks like a bug. It should throw a compile time error like Scala 2.x. You can report it in github

Comment: Confirmed in Scastie. Curious: if you turn on explicit nulls, you all of a sudden get this warning for all three `isInstanceOf` tests: "The highlighted type test will always succeed since the scrutinee type (Playground.d : => Playground.Demo) is a subtype of Object"